# I murdered my wife, is there a way to bring her back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

A while back I married Camilla Valerius. Recently I was playing and I started to get tired of Faendal always coming over to my house in Whiterun, so I murdered my wife Camilla. However, you see, Faendal is still coming to my house and I no longer get 100 gold per day.

Unfortunately I have the PS3 version so I am unable to use Console commands, and a save game is not really possibility as I have completed around 2 quests since I murdered my wife.

Is there any other way to bring back my wife on my version of the game?

Comment: Why didn't you just kill Faendal?

Answer (score 5):

No im sorry. You could use a spell called "dead thrall" to have her as a pernement undead companion but you wont get the 100 gold a day. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry you cant no way of getting her back. Not unless you want to restart the game and re marry her. Or like the other people said in here you a spell but even then you dont get any money just a zombie wife. But I say marry ysolda(give her a mammoths tusk)she's useally found near the merchant stalls or sometimes in the drunken banner. Reason for this is she gives you more..wait or sleep for a few days with out asking her about money then go up to her she gives you up to 500 or sometimes more if you don't bother her about it. The more you wait the more money you can earn. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

there is really nothing much you can do about this, but if the goddamn elf really is getting on your nerves, you could just kill him. As for the whole Camilla thing, you could just use a dead thrall... or do something comedic/sadistic/creepy with her body ;)

Answer (score -2):

You could load an older Savegame or re-marry

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: others just say that its not possible but i state 2 ways of fixing it